# Global command $ live-server on git-bash can't be found?

Tags: node.js, git-bash

When I try to run `$ live-server` globally I get the following error:

> C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

I'm thinking it must be looking in the wrong place for some reason. The following returns:

```
$ npm bin -g
```

> C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm

Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

This is followed by [node/issue 29287](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29287) which points to the [same recommendation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29287#issuecomment-524859390):

> I deleted my `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm` and `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache` and reinstalled global npm modules, and the problem ceased.
>
> It would be much better though if these steps could be avoided after upgrading/downgrading node.
> If not, then at least, make it explicit in the docs that this step may be necessary when upgrading/downgrading existing node installations.